# Average of data in a column corresponding to average of duplicate data in other column

Tags: excel, duplicates, average

I have a huge data set, column A and Column B as shown in figure. As you can see, the data in column A has duplicate entries. For example A2 to A5 has a value of 0.000965, corresponding to these values i have different values in B2 to B5. I want to modify the data such as i take the common value from A2 to A5 (0.000965) and average value of B2 to B5 and so on. I tried to use averageif function but it returns 0 value

Thanks in advance for your help[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula `=UNIQUE(A2:A12)` in `D4` to spill unique values, then formula `=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$12,D2,$B$2:$B$12)` in `E5` and drag it down.

Or use formula `=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A12),AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$12,UNIQUE(A2:A12),$B$2:$B$12))` to spill whole result at once.
Result:

[image]

Adapt ranges to your dataset.